# how to do nested if in power bi

Tags: powerbi, m

Hi I have this code but doesn't seem to work, can't find what the error is.

`MA2 = IF(AND('Rawdata'[Country]<>"AU",'Rawdata'[Country]<>"NZ"),"",IF(or(' Rawdata'[Country]="AU",'Rawdata'[Country]="NZ"),LOOKUPVALUE(Sheet1[Manual Allocation],Sheet1[Material],'Rawdata'[SKU]),"No"))`

what im trying to do is:

if country is not AU and NZ, return "", if country is AU and NZ, and the material exists in sheet1, return manual allocation column from sheet1, otherwise return "No"

thanks in advance

Comment: Do your table Rawdata and Sheet1 related? Please provide some sample data from both tables and then your expected output from them. Nested If is possible in PBI, but need a clear overview of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
MA2 = 
IF(
   NOT 'Rawdata'[Country] IN {"AU","NZ"}
   ,""
   ,LOOKUPVALUE(
        Sheet1[Manual Allocation]
        ,Sheet1[Material]
        ,'Rawdata'[SKU]
        ,"No"
    )
)
```